# 2005 ford freestyle aftermarket upgrades for Hp

Tags: ford

what are some upgrades? 
throttle body lift? 
cutout and sleeve cat? 
runs well as is. I own a 700 Polaris and want to tow it around my Colorado mountains.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

If you're serious about increasing power, you will have to spend some serious money to do it. The car is usually tuned from the factory to output an acceptable amount of power while maintaining good fuel economy. Installing a Cold Air or Short Ram Intake (CAI or SRI) system, a less restrictive exhaust, a piggyback ECU, and getting the car tuned by a professional with experience in Ford engine software can provide a noticeable increase in horsepower. Expect to pay as much as 1000 USD for a ~30hp gain, and expect to lose some fuel efficiency. In my opinion, your money would be better spent investing in a stronger tow vehicle.